# Is my understanding of this "confidence interval" Matlab solution correct?

Tags: matlab, vector, statistics

I was faced with a problem of automatically detecting regions of continuity in a vector. I have a lot of these vectors, hundreds. one example of such vector is here: http://pastebin.com/UiSkJ7Da

So basically looking at the vector one can see that there are regions of continuity, then it breaks, jumps some value and then  has another region of continuity and so on.

I was provided with this solution by some nice fellow on the newsreader:

```
v = [ 9 18 21 58 59 60 63 66 69 70 72 74 ...
dv = diff([0 v]);                                       % Create difference vector
dvs = [mean(dv)  std(dv)];                              % Determine mean & std
dvd = [0 find(dv > 1.96*dvs(2)+dvs(1)) length(v)];      % Use ‘dvs’ to detect discontinuities & create index reference vector
for k1 = 1:length(dvd)-1
    vs{k1} = v(dvd(k1)+1:dvd(k1+1)-1);                  % Create cell array of regions-of-interest
    vi{k1} = [dvd(k1)+1 dvd(k1+1)-1];                   % Create reference array of start-end indices for ‘vs’ regions
end
```

this works wonderfully and uses the 95% confidence interval to find the start and end points of the indexes of the regions.

I know it works I just want to know why and how it works.

Statistics is not my strong point, so I have been reading in detail anything I can find related to the provided solution. Can anyone strong in statistics shed some light on this.

I want to fully understand the working of the solution provided. Based on what I have read and understood this is my understanding of the explanation (Please note I have no base in stats at all so I may be going very basic here).

So to begin a 95% confidence interval is basically saying that I am 95% sure that given mean of a probability is within these limits [a, b].

And this can be calculated with the formula:

```
x +- 1.96 (std/sqrt(n))
```

where x is the mean, std is teh standard deviation and n is the sample size.

And this confidence interval applies to a normal distribution only.

So now that I have my basics done, let me try to explain my understanding of the solution.

judging by my vector and the samples were observed to be normally distributed samples (between the jumps). Knowing that these are normal distributions simply finding their confidence intervals will give the start and end point of a normally distributed sample.

And that is what is going on in this line:

```
dvd = [0 find(dv > 1.96*dvs(2)+dvs(1)) length(v)];
```

where find, finds the indexes of the points where the confidence interval equation holds true, but why the differece vector, dv? and why use it in the condition statement?

Why even create a difference vector? and why use it in the line above?

This is based on what I read today so I may be way off. Sorry for such a long read but am I on the right path? Is my understanding correct.

Statistics is really fascinating me as to how intelligently one can make assumptions based on a sample and find them to be true.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just my opinion, and I hope it doesn't appear as a cricitism - but it seems to me that the approach you're taking here has no statistical justification at all. In particular, the regions of your signal that you describe as "continuous" contain values that are not even close to normally distributed; they are pretty close to a uniform distribution, with some bumps. The stuff you're attempting with confidence intervals is unnecessary, at least for the sample signal you posted in pastebin.

The starting point of applying the `diff` is sensible - this basically gives you a discrete approximation to the derivative of your signal. Just type `figure; plot(v); figure; plot(dv);` (using your variable names from above) and you'll see what I mean - the places where you have a discontinuity in the original signal `v` correspond to places where you have a peak in the derivative `dv`.

To find these points, no need to mess around with confidence intervals, just find all the points at which `dv` rises above some threshold value. You'll need to determine exactly what threshold to use, and in your example it's pretty clear that you can choose a range of thresholds and you'll get the right results (you might have a bit of difficulty distinguishing the small discrete jump at the start from the region at the end where it gradually increases).

In a more complex example where the jumps were less obvious, you could potentially use some sort of confidence-interval-based approach to choose a threshold that would capture as many discrete jumps as possible, while excluding as many gradual increases as possible. But constructing confidence intervals always makes assumptions about the statistical properties of your data; and if you're going to do that, you need to make sure your data actually meets those assumptions. If you're using an assumption that the regions of continuity contain normally distributed values, your signal here doesn't meet that assumption.

Hope that helps. In addition, you might get better advice by asking this question on [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com) rather than here.

Comment: Thank you Sam. That was very helpful. I did try ``plot(dv)`` and it does give clear spikes at breaks but to set a threshold I would have to manually intervene for every plot of ``v``. I have hundreds of vectors, that is why I preferred an automatic solution. All of my data is like the one posted in pastebin so all of it is like you properly noted is not normally distributed but uniformly. So if I cannot make this normal distribution assumption, how can I explain the working of this confidence interval solution. This was just my basic understanding of why it works and CI needs normal distr.

Comment: I did not know http://stats.stackexchange.com/ existed. Thank you for the suggestion, I will post this question there.